# Association's attributes as model's attributes (no nesting) in active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I need the attributes of the belongs_to and has_one associations in an active model serializer be prefixed with the association name and serialize it as the model's immediate attributes. I don't want them nested,
under the model but have it flat in the same level.

For example,

```
class StudentSerializer
  attributes :name, :email
  belongs_to :school
end

class SchoolSerializer
  attributes :name, :location
end
```

For the above serializer, the output will be

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  email: 'mail@example.com',
  school: {
   id: 1,
   name: 'ABC School',
   location: 'US'
  }
}
```

But I need it as,

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  email: 'mail@example.com',
  school_id: 1,
  school_name: 'ABC School',
  school_location: 'US'
}
```

I can do this by adding the following methods to the serializer like

```
attributes :school_id, :school_name, :school_location  

def school_name
  object.school.name
end

def school_location
  object.school.location
end
```

But I don't think it's a 'great' solution as I need to define methods for all the attributes in the association. Any idea or workaround (or a direct solution if I'm missing) to achieve this elegantly? TIA.

Update: 
I've handled this with the following workaround for each association for now temporarily.

```
attributes :school_name, :school_location

[:name, :location].each do |attr|
  define_method %(school_#{attr}) do
    object.school.send(attr)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manage the virtual attributes as missing methods:

```
  attributes :school_id, :school_name, :school_location 

  def method_missing( name, *_args, &_block )
    method = name.to_s
    if method.start_with?( 'school_' )
      method.slice! 'school_'
      object.school.send( method )
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?( name, include_all = false )
    return true if name.to_s.start_with?( 'school_' )
    super
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @mat! A friend of mine suggested the same idea, but what if there are more associations? Like say `belongs_to :class`? I'll have to maintain an array of belongs_to and has_one association names and loop through them to check and return the value. The flow becomes complicated. :-(